# I just want to run this 4 containers : Portainer, odoo, postgres, traefik but traefik does not work

Tags: odoo, traefik, portainer

Portainer is an amazing tool that enables anyone to work with containers.

I can install Portainer and with it install odoo and postgres and it runs fine.

The next step is to install a proxy.

Traefik would do what I need. I can redirect multiple odoo instances to port 443

The problem is that I install traefic official image using portainer but it does not work.

Many people would like to install traefik with portainer but this case is not documented and does not work.

Very frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I had been through this. The way i solve this is using [Nginx-Proxy-Manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/) instead of Traefik. To me, it simply make more sense to have precise control over routes(home lab server etc) in easy to manage visual way.